# how to browse a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm new to jQuery. Following is the `data` variable that contains a json dictionary.

```
{
   "user":null, 
   "currency":"EUR",
   "balance":0,
   "translist": [ 
       { "trans1":"something","trans2":"something2" }
   ]
}
```

and my jQuery method receives a `json/Javascript object` from the Rest `GET` call

```
success: function (data){    
        for(x in data) {
            console.log(x + ':   ' + data[x]);
        }       
    });
```

Is there any library that can help to parse/walk through this json object and get to some kind of objects list? I want to check some of the keys and their respective values. Problem is I don't need all the keys and values from the list and also some of the values can be null, which prevented me to apply some solutions I found using SO.

Or usually is it more common to directly start printing the HTML inside the success function?

EDIT:If it was java for example it would be a Map and I would use an iterator to walk through and see/analyse the map values, and create some array list with the values I want from it. What's equivalent of that in jQuery?

Comment: You don't need any library to walk in a js object. What access/iteration is a problem to you ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the Objects properties

Comment: "my JQuerry method receives a Json "object" " — There's no such thing, that's just a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Quentin +1 I don't see those anymore...

Comment: You are also missing a } before the ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If it was java for example it would be a Map and I would use an
>   iterator to walk through and see/analyse the map values, and create
>   some arraylist with the values I want in it. What is the equivalent of that
>   in jQuery?

[Any javascript object can be seen as an associative map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

You can for example directly access the currency as `data['currency']`.

You can also build an array :

```
var a = [];
for (var key in data) {
    a.push({key:key, value:data[key]});
}
```

You could also build some HTML and apply functions to the data :

```
$(document.body).append($(
   '<table>' + a.map(function(v){
      return '<tr><td>'+v.key+'</td><td>'+v.value+'</td></tr>'
   }).join('')+'</table>'
));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/G2nUk/)

Using jQuery can make the same iteration simpler (working directly from `data`) :

```
$(document.body).append($(
   '<table>' + $.map(data, function(value,key){
      return '<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+value+'</td></tr>'
   }).join('')+'</table>'
));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/TWLPY/)

Comment: and how can i get the sub array elements of transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `each`

```
success: function (data){   
    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        if(key === "currency")
            alert( key + ": " + value );
    });   
});
```

Comment: he said he does not want all `key, values`