# jQuery iterate through JSON dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For this JSON dictionary,

```
{
"user":null, 
"currency":"EUR",
"balance":0,
"tranlist": [ 
   { "date":"323","address":"a"},
   { "date":"121","address":"s"},
 ]
}
```

When I use this function, I have problem with getting the Transactions List

```
$(document.body).append($(
 '<table>' + $.map(data, function(value,key){
     return '<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+value+'</td></tr>'
  }).join('')+'</table>'
));
```

And here is output:

```
 currency   EUR
 balance    0
 transactions   [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you show ([that I wrote in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212005/how-to-browse-a-javascript-object/14212124#14212124)) was intended for a fast preview of your structure and as an example of object browsing.

Now you must make some code more specific to your problem. For example :

```
  $(document.body).append($(
     '<table>' + $.map(data, function(value,key){
         console.log(value);
         return '<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'
             + ((value && $.isArray(value))
                 ? value.map(function(v){return v.date+':'+v.address}).join(', ')
                 : value
             )+ '</td></tr>'
      }).join('')+'</table>'
    ));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/tSX7F/)

You could also devise a generic and recursive toString function but apart debugging (and `console.log` is better for that), there isn't much point.

Comment: tnx this works but I am confused, why the key shows the title and the value shows the value, while your functions parameters are (value,key) but not (key,value)

Comment: Because [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) passes the value before the key. It's the same order as in [anyArray.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: could you also look this one? tnx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236448/jqueery-mobile-changepage-does-not-work-properly

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document.body).append(
    $('<table>').append(
      $.map(data, function (value, key) {
        return $('<tr>').append( $('<td>', {text: key}) )
                        .append( $('<td>', {text: value}) );
      })
    );
));
```

Note that it's not recommendable to build HTML from concatenating strings. Constructing elements with a separation of markup and data `$('<td>', {text: key})` is the cleanest solution.

Comment: I'm not sure it's not recommendable. It's generally recommended to build a big HTML string instead of appending multiple small elements.

Comment: @dystroy This is not something I would call a good practice. If the data contains user input or other funny bits of format then you open a hole for XSS attacks this way, which is bad, obviously. Concatenation (when done right) happens to be a little bit faster, so it is an *optimization*. But in this case I'd make sure that the data does not contain HTML, which is a step that most people forget. Squeezing out two dozen milliseconds in page run time will not be necessary in most cases, so I'd always recommend the clean and secure method.

Comment: @Tomalak tnx but I dont see anything as output, am I missing something?

Comment: @Spring Woops, my bad. I forgot the angle brackets with `$('<table>' ...)`. Of course the nested objects will still be output as `[object Object]`, since you did not say how to handle them.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly answer to your question but instead of build HTML on your own I would suggest using [Pure JavaScript Template Engine](http://beebole.com/pure/) for that (jQuery plugin).

The engine (a jQuery plugin) is very light and it is great for type of job you do (especially iterating over children elements).

I would suggest you spend literately a few minutes going though [Get Started](http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/get-started/) page and a few [tutorials](http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/tutorials/) explaining iteration over children element.

---

Example using PURE

**HTML code**:

```
<div id="sample">
  <div class="currency">EUR</div>
  <div class="balance">0</div>
  <table>
    <tr class="date">
      <td>date</td><td class="value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="address">
      <td>address</td><td class="value"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<div>
```

**JavaScript code** (please note that `data` variable used in the last statement is the same as the one in your question)

```
//declaration of the actions PURE has to do
var directive = {
  '.currency': 'currency',
    '.balance': 'balance',
    'table': {
    'trans<-tranlist': {
      'tr.date .value': 'trans.date',
      'tr.address .value': 'trans.address'
    }
  }
};

// note the use of render instead of autoRender
$('#sample').render(data, directive);
```

Output **HTML** would be as follows:

```
<div id="sample">
  <div class="currency"></div>
  <div class="balance"></div>
  <table>
    <tr class="date">
      <td>date</td><td class="value">323</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="address">
      <td>address</td><td class="value">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="date">
      <td>date</td><td class="value">121</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="address">
      <td>address</td><td class="value">s</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<div>
```

Of course you could do much more like setting class attributes from JSON object or filtering items etc.