# jQuery mobile .changePage does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

This is a user login screen, when login successful I want to show another page, this "kinda" works but after successful login I get a mixture of both pages! it is all overlayed. So only when I refresh the page I can see it properly. I also tried to use jQuery version 1.6.4 but didn't help.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
   $.ajax({
   ...
   success: function (data){ 

      $.mobile.changePage('account.html'); 
 },
    });
</script>
```

**Also** apart from overlay issue on the next page there is a JavaScript code which does not work until I refresh the page.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".infoBasic").click(function() {
     $(this).next('.infoDetails').slideToggle("50");
 });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues here:

jQuery Mobile 1.1 only work with core jQuery verysions 1.6.4 and 1.7.1 while Mobile 1.2 works with core 1.7.0 and 1.8.2

`$(document).ready()` is not supported. Use `$(document).bind('pageinit')` instead. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Your script references should not start with `//` but `http://`

Comment: when I use  $(document).bind("pageinit", function() problem partially solved , but cant get css until I refresh teh page. changing versions made it only worse so I kept as it is. any suggestions for css?

Comment: You may in addition need to call refresh on your widget. `$("#myButton").button("refresh");` or `$("#myPage").page("destroy").page();`

Comment: I used window.location.replace() and it worked in desktop browser, is that ok to use it mobile?

Comment: and could you explain how can i use that mybutton refresh trick in my code? tnx

Comment: not sure about navigating with window.location... jQuery Mobile uses progressive enhancement to your markup based on `data-` annotations. If you modify CSS or HTML, jQM will likely need to re-enhance the markup so you call `("refresh")` on the widget.

Comment: I dont have a button or div here, I dont know what to refresh, can I refresh all page?

Comment: `$("#myPage").page("destroy").page();` will force the entire page to refresh. I see others doing it but it might be a bit unconventional.

Comment: could you look at this one? tnx! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609080/jquery-mobile-how-to-detect-refresh

Comment: @Spring, that answer looks as good as I can possibly suggest. not sure how to connect but if you need help or want to chat off line, glad to.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this i think:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success : function(data) {
        $('body').empty();
        $.mobile.changePage('account.html');
    },
});
```

For your second problem, you should use delegation with .on():

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(this).on('click',".infoBasic",function() {
        $(this).next('.infoDetails').slideToggle("50");
    });

});
```

Comment: tnx I updated the question, ur solution helped partially helped to clean the page, still not working tho